# Wordpress - how to avoid list style type?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to use the following shortcode in a wordpress theme to display the dropbox logo:

```
[pt_social_icon iconsize="standard" service="dropbox" url="" ]
```

However, whenever I create a textbox and write the code in the html, the dropbox logo has a bullet point next to it, as if the system is recognizing it as a listed object. I have tried the following, but it still hasn't worked.

```
a.dropbox.standard.ptwsi-social-icon {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: can you add HTML generated by the short code

Comment: You need to change the list style type not on the a link but the ul or ol it's in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the element has a before (or after) element attached to it. Try to set the display attribute of the after and before element to none.